# systemd-boot Install Failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, systemd-boot

I am replacing GRUB with systemd-boot on a multiboot system with several instances of Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 on discrete partitions because the instances are competing for control of the bootloader grubx64.efi and systemd-boot apparently manages this better.

The installation is failed and resisting configuration.  In particular, systemd-boot ignores configured boot entries and often the system boots to the grub shell, requiring manual boot.

The process I followed was as recommended.  The ESP is /dev/sda1 and by default is mounted to /boot/efi.  Boot partitions are /dev/sda2-7, with 2, 4, and 7 the most relevant and the others only provisionally configured.  First, I ran:

```
# bootctl install
```

I then configured /boot/efi/loader/loader.conf:

```
#       /boot/efi/loader/loader.conf
#       systemd-boot configuration file    
timeout 5
#default 4fa9a5bf4498415ead7dea7c2724e90a-*
#       From man loader.conf, Options, default, at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loader.conf.html:
default @saved
console-mode keep
```

I then configured the boot entries in .conf files in /boot/efi/loader/entries, all of which are in the form of:

```
#       /boot/efi/loader/entries/sdx4.conf
#       Boot entry configuration file.    
title sdx4 - Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
linux ../vmlinuz
initrd ../initrd.img
options root=PARTUUID=9d1de6a4-452c-42d2-bf18-acee90032326 rw
```

Then, on the recommended reboot, systemd-boot presents a menu with options only for the default boot loader, which boots to the GRUB shell, and to boot into the EFI configuration utility.

Kernel files remain in /boot because linux-update-symlinks creates the symlinks initrd.img and vmlinuz in /boot and FAT32 does not support symlinks.

```
bootctl status
```

returns

```
System:
     Firmware: n/a (n/a)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user
 TPM2 Support: no
 Boot into FW: supported

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: n/a
     Features: ✗ Boot counting
               ✗ Menu timeout control
               ✗ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✗ Default entry control
               ✗ One-shot entry control
               ✗ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✗ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✗ Boot loader sets ESP information
          ESP: n/a
         File: └─n/a

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: no
 System Token: set
       Exists: yes

Available Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7)
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: ubuntu
           ID: 0x0000
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7
         File: └─/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

        Title: ubuntu
           ID: 0x0002
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7
         File: └─/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi

        Title: Linux Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0001
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

        Title: UEFI OS
           ID: 0x0005
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

        Title: ubuntu
           ID: 0x0006
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7
         File: └─EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi

Boot Loader Entries:
        $BOOT: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/3aa3442b-045b-4b22-8e8b-6c01a5571ce7)

Default Boot Loader Entry:
        title: sdx7 - Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
           id: sdx7.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/sdx7.conf
        linux: ../vmlinuz
       initrd: ../initrd.img
      options: root=PARTUUID=67027db9-885b-471b-9c01-4b2108e6f7e9 rw

tree /boot/efi
```

returns

```
/boot/efi/EFI
├── BOOT
│   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   └── mmx64.efi
├── debian
│   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubx64.efi
│   ├── mmx64.efi
│   └── shimx64.efi
├── Linux
├── systemd
│   └── systemd-bootx64.efi
└── ubuntu
    ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    ├── grub.cfg
    ├── grubx64.efi
    ├── mmx64.efi
    └── shimx64.efi

5 directories, 14 files
```

This is a disaster.  None of the documentation provides a clue, nor does Google.  Any constructive thoughst about how to get systemd-boot to work would be appreciated.

Comment: I forget the details now but I got systemd-boot working well by following the guidance of the Arch wiki where I think you will find links to the authors web pages. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot

Comment: @PonJar, thanks.  Naturally, I exhausted the available online resources including your recommendation before posting.  Sadly, I remain stuck.  Did you recall whether you installed before installing GRUB, or any (or multiple) OSs?

Comment: I started with Windows 10 only . No grub no linux. I added arch to the machine and systemd-boot. Added the entry for arch and it worked first time showing arch, Windows and boot to firmware. Happy to share configurations but I am away from home for another 10 days or so. I think you need to remove grub using a chroot from a live environment

Comment: I think I recall rodsbook.com being helpful for this. It’s a bit of a goldmine for all sorts of things Linux. This link may help http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html

Comment: @PonJar, good information.  I've been on to rodsbooks already, also, and it is excellent but not on point.  Regarding our configs, I expect my situation is complicated by multiple Ubuntu instances competing for the boot loader.  I am curious about your configuration although I expect it is similar those recommended.

Comment: Been able to think about this and a couple of things could be relevant. Your linux and initrd entries look odd to me. I’m pretty sure my vmlinuz and initrd.img files are below the esp in the file structure. In fact I have multiple files to support a range of kernels. According to the Arch wiki they should be relative to the esp. I doubt they can be above the esp since it would be mounted to /boot only after everything has started. I would move those files somewhere below the esp and try again

Comment: @PonJar, that's a good observation.  I'm aware of that.  The Boot Loader Specification does not require or recommend that those files be on the ESP, only that they be on the same partition as one another.  Also, Ubuntu places kernel files in /boot, creates the generic symlinks vmlinuz, vmlinuz.old, initrd.img, and initrd.img.old to the current and prior kernel files, mounts the ESP to /boot/efi, and the ESP's VFAT format does not support symlinks.  Consequently, I simply set the linux and initrd entries to reference the ESP's parent directory so periodic updates would not disrupt boot entries.

Comment: My point was that the esp doesn’t have a parent directory at the time the process needs those files. Mine works and they below the esp. I understand it’s only mounted later to facilitate updates. Arch has a hook that is simply a process to find and update those files as necessary. Ubuntu is designed for grub so may need a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [systemd-boot](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-boot.html) does not implement the [Boot Loader Specification](https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION/).  The command `bootctl list` is the syntax checker for boot loader entries conforming with the latter according to its [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootctl.html#list) and returns:

```
    title: sdx3 - Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
       id: sdx3.conf
   source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/sdx3.conf
    linux: ../vmlinuz
   initrd: ../initrd.img
  options: root=PARTUUID=[UUID redacted] rw

    title: sdx4 - Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
       id: sdx4.conf
   source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/sdx4.conf
    linux: /vmlinuz (No such file or directory)
   initrd: /initrd.img (No such file or directory)
  options: root=PARTUUID=[UUID redacted] rw
```

So it is that we see that specifying the kernel files' location as being in the parent directory of the EFI System Partition's mount point by using the ../ path conforms not only with the language of the Boot Loader Specification (which I should hasten to add contains no language requiring kernel files to be located on the ESP) but also with the code that implements it.

Someone besides me has wasted a lot of effort.

Das Gummiboot wird gesunken.

The way to float the wreck is not to conform with the Boot Loader Specification, the syntax checker, or any of the other documentation but instead, as @PonJar has noted, to move the kernel files to the ESP.

This requires a cascade of reconfigurations including hand-writing a number of installation scripts to overhaul the kernel installation / upgrade process, and actually uprooting the kernel files for transplant to the ESP (huh?).  The tail wags the dog.

Conforming systemd-boot with the Boot Loader Specification, specifically by enabling it to read kernel files wherever located including on the filesystem of the partition being booted, would make the entirety of the foregoing unnecessary.

Indeed, systemd-boot seems to be architecturally flawed and tries to do too much.  The `kernel-install` command and its related `bootctl` options all exist simply to compensate for systemd-boot's execution limitations or those of systemd-bootx64.efi.  It is a boot loader, after all, and its entire purpose is execute a kernel on another partition but it cannot and this complexity is the consequence.

If systemd-boot could execute a kernel where and as installed, all the configuration necessary would be loader.conf and the /loader/entries .conf files.

The procedure, which I gleaned directly and otherwise from [this post](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/tutorial-convert-to-systemd-boot/13290), and with thanks to the poster dalto, involves:

- Mount the ESP to `/boot/efi`
- Install efibootmgr; Remove grub*
- Remove all instances of `zz-update-grub` from subdirectories of `/etc/kernel`
- Copy all kernel command lines otherwise appearing in `/etc/default/grub` under `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `/etc/kernel/cmdline`
- Do `# bootctl install`
- Create and mark as executable `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-systemd-boot`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh -e

  version="$1"
  bootopt=""

  # passing the kernel version is required    
  if [ -z "${version}" ]; then
          echo >&2 "W: kernel-install: ${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE:-kernel package} did not pass a version number"
          exit 2
  fi

  # exit if kernel does not need an initramfs

  if [ "$INITRD" = 'No' ]; then
          exit 0
  fi

  # avoid running multiple times

  if [ -n "$DEB_MAINT_PARAMS" ]; then'

          eval set -- "$DEB_MAINT_PARAMS"

          if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" != "configure" ]; then

                  exit 0

          fi
  fi

  kernel-install add "$version" "/boot/vmlinuz-$version"
  ```
- Create and mark as executable `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-systemd-boot`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh -e

  version="$1"
  bootopt=""

  # passing the kernel version is required
  if [ -z "${version}" ]; then

          echo >&2 "W: kernel-install: ${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE:-kernel package} did not pass a version number"

          exit 2
  fi

  kernel-install remove "$version"
  ```
- Do:

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/initramfs/post-update.d

  cd /etc/initramfs/post-update.d/ && sudo ln -s ../../kernel/postinst.d/zz-systemd-boot zz-systemd-boot
  ```
- Finally run kernel-install for the current kernel.

Pending the next rev of systemd-boot, may the Force be with you.

Comment: Your “this post” link doesn’t work. Also there appear to be issues with the formatting of some of the code. Interesting answer though. Arch has no problem updating the kernel etc on my install. It’s the only reason the esp gets mounted to /boot.

Comment: @PonJar, it looks as if the entire EndeavourOS site is down.  None of my bookmarks there work.  No idea what's up.  As for the code, the formatting interface here choked on the octothorpes at the beginning of the comment lines, and selectively ignored newlines, so I had to insert spaces or additional newlines manually, so it is authentically ugly and nothing more can be done that I'm aware of.  Otherwise, the Ubuntu kernel update on one of the partitions failed just now, so this is a failed hack.  I'll need to revisit once the EndeavourOS site is back up.

Comment: @PonJar the site is back up and the link now works.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer but I'm sharing my configuration in the expectation that it will lead you to your own answer.

The contents of my efi partition are as follows:

```
tree -L 1
.
├── EFI
├── gparted
├── initramfs-linux-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux.img
├── initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux-lts.img
├── intel-ucode.img
├── loader
├── System Volume Information
├── vmlinuz-linux
└── vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

This gives me the Arch linux mainline kernel and lts kernel plus an option to boot gparted live.

The loader directory contains:

```
.
├── entries
│   ├── arch.conf
│   ├── arch_lts.conf
│   ├── clonezilla.conf
│   └── gparted.conf
├── loader.conf
└── random-seed
```

The arch.conf file contains:

```
title   Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /intel-ucode.img
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=UUID=66f01fdf-82a1-4aef-a7f6-27b3ba7bb790 rw
```

The gparted.conf file contains:

```
title   GParted Live
linux   gparted/live/vmlinuz
initrd  gparted/live/initrd.img
options apm=power-off boot=live live-media-path=/gparted/live/ username=user noswap noeject  ip= net.ifnames=0
```

I am as certain as I can be that all you need to do is get rid of the two dots in the

```
linux ../vmlinuz 
initrd ../initrd.img
```

part of your conf file.

If you are interested the gparted conf file boots an extracted copy of the gparted live iso which is on the efi partition in the gparted directory. It uses the gparted initrd.img and vmlinuz which are located down the gparted directory tree.

Hope this leads you to a working solution. Note that the initrd.img and vmlinuz files have to be on the efi FAT partition which is "/" when the boot process starts